# which preposition sounds more idiomatic and natural?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idioms, prepositions, conversation

which one to use to mean  that people die because of flu ?

1- People die from flu.
2- People die of flu.

Comment: Please give a full sentence that provides some context - thanks.

Comment: @ Greybeard   The sentence : Comparing the new virus with the normal flu, people normally die of/from flu .

Comment: "from" sounds more natural to me. But it's common to say "of <disease>" as well.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for the useful details.